# IE not converting string to HTML using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-9, innerhtml

I am passing a string to a table where some of the classes contains html markup in a string (img).  After a conversion post appending this table using innerHTML works great in chrome and FF but not IE.

Here is the code that looks something like this:

```
var dfd = $.Deferred();
        var requestParams = {};
        templatingIsDone = jsonRequest(ResolveUrl("~/Results/ResultsService.asmx/GetMostRecentUploadsService"), requestParams).success(function (data) {
            if (data.Success == true) {
                var jheaderResults = $("#jobheaderResults tbody");  //HTML Markup
                try {
                    jheaderResults.empty();
                    var results = data.Results;

                    $.tmpl("jobHeaderTemplate", data.Results).appendTo(jheaderResults);

                    var allCaterLinks = $(".CaterRequestLinking");
                    $.each(allCaterLinks, function (index, value) {
                        if ($.browser.msie) {
                            value.innerHTML = value.innerText;
                        } else {
                            value.innerHTML = value.textContent;
                        }
                    });

                    $("#jobheaderResults tbody").trigger("update");
```

The result shows its image in Firefox and Chrome in the table "jobheaderResults".  However IE does not render the image and instead shows the html markup instead.  How do I convert this to HTML?

I have also tried the following code but to no avail:

```
                  //value.innerHTML = value.empty().html(value.innerHTML);
                  //value.innerHTML = value.textContent;
                  //value.innerHTML = value.innerHTML.html();
                  //value.html(value.innerText);
                  //value.innerHTML = value.outerText;
```

None of the above worked, they all failed to render the image onto IE.

For extra information, the actual markup that I am trying to convert is:

```
"<a href=\"#\" class=\"caterReqClass\"><img src=\"/HWVDB/images/Cater-Icon.jpg\" alt=\"CaterReqAlternate\"/></a>"
```

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/276228
I remember something a while back about innerHTML failing in IE. The work around was to grab the element in the DOM and .appendChild to it. Have you tried that yet?

Comment: I tried using the jquery append function, but under the $.each function it just fails.  Have not tried the .appendChild function from DOM element, will give this a shot.  I am hoping to stay within the confines of jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
    $.each(allCaterLinks, function () {
        $('.allCaterLinks').html($('.allCaterLinks').text());
    });
```

This should work in all browsers. From jQuery.com: "This (.html()) method uses the browser's innerHTML property. Some browsers may not return HTML that exactly replicates the HTML source in an original document. For example, Internet Explorer sometimes leaves off the quotes around attribute values if they contain only alphanumeric characters."

Comment: I did try this before and after using the IE debugger it complained:

Object doesn't support property or method 'text'

After this I also tried : value.html(value.innerText);

Object doesn't support property or method 'html'

Comment: Also to confirm , I am using IE9.  And ofcourse all my jquery libraries are all included.

Comment: That's probably because you're using the value from the function itself. I think you could get away with using $('.allCaterLinks').html($('.allCaterLinks').text()); because you don't need to get values from specific indices of your selector.

Comment: Apparantly changing to IE9 viewer and changing the code to `code`value.innerHTML = value.innerText did work!! But only in IE9 view , anything below IE9 does not seem to render the image